# Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. 'XML is not valid

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm not sure what happened with my xaml code, but after I uploaded my code to github my xaml code broke, I'm getting over 200 error messages.

Please see this screenshot for a few of them:

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbCCF.jpg)

Can anyone help me?

The `system.xml` dll is added correctly, I tried cleaning and rebuilding it but didn't help

This is my XAML markup:

```
<Window x:Class="solutionsinternaltesting.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:solutionsinternaltesting"
         xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:PlaceholderTextBoxControlloer;assembly=PlaceholderTextBoxControlloer"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="1300"
        WindowStyle="None"
        >

    <Window.Resources>

        <ContextMenu x:Key="TextBoxContextMenu" x:Shared="False">
            <MenuItem Header="Cut" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" />
            <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
            <MenuItem Header="Paste" Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" />
            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="ApplicationCommands.Delete" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Select All" Command="ApplicationCommands.SelectAll" />
        </ContextMenu>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />


        <Style x:Key="GlowTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <!-- Style content -->
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0" Opacity="0" ShadowDepth="0" Color="DodgerBlue" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Opacity="0.8" ShadowDepth="0" Color="DodgerBlue" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource GlowTextBoxStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                CornerRadius="5">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="CustomButtonsStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF4CAFAD"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0,20,10,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#FF38748E"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="#FFD3D3D3"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#A0A0A0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.6" Color="#FF888484"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#A0A0A0 "/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.7" ShadowDepth="3"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate" TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Ellipse x:Name="RadioButtonOuterEllipse" Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Ellipse x:Name="RadioButtonInnerEllipse" Width="10" Height="5" Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="RadioButtonInnerEllipse" Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>


    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

       <rest of the code..... />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Did you already check the Build Action for your file(s) as described in [WPF XAML parsing error. "Data at the root level is invalid."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39668217/205233)

Comment: it has the build action of Page